# Name of these matrices: 1 for entries a fixed distance from main diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request

I'm interested in matrices that are (i) square $n\times n$, (ii) has entries $0$ and $1$ only (iii) on each row, all the $1$'s are located a fixed distance $d<n$ from the main diagonal elements. What are these matrices called and can you please link to sources that discuss their properties? (Strictly speaking, I'm interested in $\frac{1}{2}$ times these matrices but I'll appreciate help either way.)

**Examples**: with $n=4,d=0$, we get the identity matrix $I_4$. With $n=4,d=1$, we have
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
and with $n=4$, $d=2$, we have
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: All of these matrices are [Toeplitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) $\{0,1\}$-matrices, and your first example is a [tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Eigenvalues).  I'm not sure if there's anything nice which can be said about their general properties.

Comment: It might also be useful to interpret these as the adjacency matrices of certain graphs.

Comment: Actually, based on my last comment: I have a hunch that all of these graphs will be adjacency matrices of a union of path graphs

Comment: What kind of properties are you looking for?  Anything specific?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'm looking at quadratic forms $x'Ax$ where $A$ is one of these matrices. I'm trying to see what I can say about $x'Ax$ and $(x'Ax)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's helpful to consider only the case where $d \neq 0$, since $d = 0$ is a bit of a special case.  Let $A(d,n)$ denote the matrix in which we have set $d$ equal to $d$ and $n$ equal to $n$ (so, your second example is $A(1,4)$).

Two interesting decompositions:

First, let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denote the canonical basis.  If we set $P$ equal to the permutation matrix
$$
P = \pmatrix{e_1 & e_{1 + d} & e_{1 + 2d} & \cdots & e_2 & e_{2 + d} & e_{2 + 2d} \cdots & \cdots}
$$
Then we find that 
$$
P^TA(d,n)P = \pmatrix{A(1,n_1)\\ & A(1,n_2) && \\ &&\ddots \\ &&& A(1,n_k)}
$$
where $n_i$ is the length of the sequence $i,i + d, i + 2d, \dots, 1 + n_id$; $n_i$ is the largest integer such that $i + n_i d \leq n$ (that is, $n_i = \lfloor (n - i)/d\rfloor$).

We can decompose $A(1,n)$ in a more informative way by noting that if we set
$$
Q = 
\begin{cases}
\pmatrix{e_1 & e_3 & \cdots & e_{n-1} & e_2 & e_4 & \cdots & e_{n}} & \text{n is even}\\
\pmatrix{e_1 & e_3 & \cdots & e_{n} & e_2 & e_4 & \cdots & e_{n-1}} & \text{n is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
then we find that
$$
Q^TA(1,n)Q = \pmatrix{0 & B\\B^T & 0}
$$
where $B$ is the identity matrix of size $n/2$ when $n$ is even, and the identity matrix of size $(n-1)/2$ with an extra row of zeros when $n$ is odd.

With all that being said, your matrices are the adjacency matrices of the union of path graphs, which in particular means that they are all the adjacency matrices of [bipartite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) graphs.  We can conclude that the eigenvalues of $A$ will always come in $\pm$ pairs, so the positive signature of your bilinear form will be exactly equal to its negative signature.

It may also be useful to consider the full eigendecomposition of $A(1,n)$: since $A$ is [tridiagonal and Toeplitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Eigenvalues), we can quickly find that its eigenvalues are of the form $- \cos(k \pi/(n + 1))$ for $k = 1, \dots, n$.  In particular, we see that $A(1,n)$ has no repeated eigenvalues and that it is singular (with nullity at most $1$) if and only if $n$ is odd.

---

Second, define $M$ by
$$
M = \pmatrix{1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
 \vdots & 0\\
0  & \vdots & \cdots\\
1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
\vdots & 0\\
& \vdots}
$$
Where the $0 \cdots 0$ denotes $d-1$ consecutive zeros, and the final column ends in a $1$, with no trailing zeros.  We can then express your matrix $A$ as
$$
A = MM^T - D
$$
where $D$ is a diagonal matrix of the form $D = \operatorname{diag}(1, \dots, 1,2 \dots , 2,1 ,\dots, 1)$. This decomposition was obtained using the [incidence matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix) of the associated graph.

This doesn't seem as immediately useful to me, but maybe you'll find something here.

Comment: I've realized that my $Q$ decomposition is incompatible with my paragraph about the eigendecomposition, so one of those must be incorrect.  If someone figures out which it is, I'd be curious to know.